# Best way to conditionally attach event to element appearing only on some pages?

Tags: javascript

I'm (finally) learning to use events, and have been wondering whether my approach at the conditional attachment of events to elements is the best way to go about it.

Say you have some JavaScript that attaches a click event to an element with the ID "button":

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick=function();
```

Since I employ my main .js sitewide, it is often the case that some pages may contain an element with the "button" ID, but many others do not. In the latter case, the console logs an error (cannot set property).

So I work around that like so:

```
if(document.getElementById('button')) {
    document.getElementById('button').onclick=function();
}
```

Or in shortened form:

```
var t = document.getElementById('button');
if(t) {
    t.onclick=function();
}
```

It works, but for some reason feels a little unwholesome. Is there perhaps a better way?

Comment: Side note: unless `someFunction` returns a function, you should be assigning it to `onclick`, not call it and assign its return value.

Comment: If doing a *thing* to X when X does not exist causes an error, you are always going to have to check that X exists.

Comment: @FelixKling Good point, that was sloppy of me. Fixed that above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is fine. If you wanted to add jQuery, it would handle the test for you.

Comment: In a similar fashion, I presume? But by wrapping it in a function?

Comment: Yes, in jQuery your code would be: `$('#button').click(function);`. Jquery applies the code to every element that matches the CSS-style selector. If zero elements match, the call does nothing. With an ID selector (#) you will have either zero or one match.

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI `onclick` is the old way to assign a click event. It will only allow one function to be assigned.    Unless you are supporting IE8 or earlier, I recommend using `addEventListener()` which is a more modern approach.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

```
var el =document.getElementById('button');
if (el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function (){
    alert('hi!');
  }, false);
}
```

Yes, you should check that it exists before it's added.

Comment: Since the actual event wasn't the focus of my question, I thought I'd keep it simple by using onload in my examples. I'm actually using a function that applies either addEventListener, attachEvent or the older onclick et al, depending on the browser's capabilities. Good point, though.